# jquery asp.net button visibility

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visibility, aspbutton

There is some code like this :

```
if ( bValid ) { 
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
$("#btnExcel").show(); }
```

and .aspx look like :

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
                    <input id="inpHide" type="hidden" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnExcel" runat="server" Text="Excel" AccessKey="E" BorderWidth="0px"
                        OnClick="btnExcel_Click" ToolTip="Excel" Visible="false" />
                    </form>

`bValid` is some part of code
```

Why this doesnt work ?
What can be done to work it out.
To make button visisble ?

may be its not accessible because :

```
var button = $('#btnExcel')[0]; 
                        alert(button);
```

shows : undefined !

Looking for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have the button as Visible="false" on the server side. That is in your ASPX page you need to have it Visible="true" because otherwise the button is not rendered to html.

You could set the style attirbute (or CssStyle attirbute) on your button to style="display:none;" and then things will work

```
<asp:Button ID="btnExcel" runat="server" Text="Excel" AccessKey="E" BorderWidth="0px"
                        OnClick="btnExcel_Click" ToolTip="Excel" Visible="true" style="display:none;" />
```

Comment: Thanks Visible="false"  To Visible="true"  Right ??

Comment: Yes, and then set the style attribute as I've shown in the code in my answer. That is style="display: none;"

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the button's display to none?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the IDs of server controls generated by ASP.Net is different in the browser. View the HTML source in the browser, find the correct control ID and use that in the jQuery code. You can also try ClientID function of ASP.Net

See this for more: http://forums.asp.net/p/1522697/3664258.aspx

Comment: The button is not rendered to html since it has been set to false on the server side. ASP controls when set to false are not rendered.

Answer (score 0):

`btnExcel` will be mangled since its a server side control.

Obtain the mangled id as `document.getElementByid(<%=btnExcel.ClientID%>)`

Comment: There will be no button in fact (in html), since it's Visible property is false.